# What is the purpose of the .tmp directory the Yeoman Gruntfile uses

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

A common pattern in Gruntfiles when preprocessing CSS and JS is to compile the output to a .tmp directory , process it (say with Autoprefixer or Uglify) and then copy it into the destination directory. Particularly when serving locally (eg with grunt-contrib-connect)

eg: app/sass > compile to .tmp/css > autoprefix and minify > move to dist/css

Why would this be a benefit to processing in one place and moving to the destination directory immediately? 
eg: app/sass > compile to app/css > autoprefix and minify > move to dist/

or am I misunderstanding the whole thing? :S

Comment: Well it's a temporary/working folder that contains files that are not yet 100% generated... It's just a pattern in order to not mix build's workflow files with build final files.

Comment: So essentially, I should only move things into DIST when all the other tasks have been completed on my file?

Comment: Yeah but this .tmp folder is generally used by grunt plugins in the background without you noticing it (though, I don't really know yeoman specifically)

Comment: @Cétia, please add your comment as an actual answer. Comments should not be used to answer the question. Alternatively (I just saw your stats), in order to not offend you seeing as you are a seasoned SO user, maybe I misunderstood. Please explain why you did it as a comment :)

Comment: @Redfox05 No reason, I must have been lazy and did not provide a full and well detailed answer :)

Comment: All good :) So I've built on the .tmp folder idea and do other things in a .concat folder, then copy to the .tmp folder. It seems to work well, hopefully its the right way though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a temporary/working folder that contains files that are not yet 100% generated... It's just a pattern in order to not mix build's workflow files with build final files.

This .tmp folder is generally used by grunt plugins in the background without you noticing it.